# GET request with cookies having secure flag set

Tags: javascript, html, security, cookies

I have saved my session cookies with secure flag set. As the browser will be sending the cookies with every XHR, I can see that the cookies which are being sent are not having the security=secure flag set. How can I ensure that while sending the XHR, the cookies are also sent with secure flag? (i.e. security=secure)

Comment: Flags such as `secure` are set in the _response_ header that set the cookie. To send it with _requests_ would make no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can see that the cookies which are being sent are not having the security=secure flag set

That is correct. The cookie specification requires that clients send only the cookie value in the `Cookie:` header, and not the metadata (`secure`, `domain`, etc). This is true for all HTTP requests, XHR or otherwise.

A shortcoming of this design is that you can't tell from the server side where a cookie was originally set. A cookie coming to you on `https://www.example.com/` might actually have been set from `http://www.example.com/` but without the `secure` flag. It could also have come from `http://other-subdomain.example.com/`, setting the `domain` to `example.com`. There is no way to know.

About all you can do to mitigate the possibility of a man-in-the-middle attacker using an unprotected connection to `http://www.example.com/` to inject cookies into `https://www.example.com/` is to use `https:` exclusively. On the `http` port instead serve a redirect to `https:` and set an [HTTP Strict Transport Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) header to try to prevent browsers from connecting to the `http:` address in future.

Comment: You can also register your domain on https://hstspreload.appspot.com/ so that it is included in the HSTS preloaded list, which prevents this mitigation being limited to Trust On First Use.